# How to recheck primary/foreign key constraint for data already in the table in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, check-constraints

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 with a foreign key and it was disable for huge data loading, and then re-enabled:

Example:

```
alter table table1 nocheck constraint fk_1
go
lots of inserts...
go
alter table table1 check constraint fk_1
go
```

Now, the question: is there a way to re-check this just inserted data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax looks a little silly with the word "check" repeated, but what you want is:

```
alter table table1 with check check constraint fk_1
go
```

Adding the "with check" option will validate existing data against the constraint. Doing this will also prevent the constraint from becoming [untrusted](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/03/can-you-trust-your-constraints/).

If any existing data violates the constraint, you'll get an error that will look like this:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "fk_1".
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: +1 for the point about untrusted constraints. It's almost never a good idea to enable constraints using WITH CHECK. Always use WITH CHECK CHECK. It's a stupid syntax but it makes all the difference.